# What Certucatuib do I need to work the back in?

Tags: community

I want to work for Salesforce but I don't know what certificate I should get to be an expert in working backin of? I didn't finish college and I know their are trade schools out there that will be just as good I'm just not sure what ones and what certificate count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go to this link and see Salesforce certification tracks available 
http://certification.salesforce.com/
And to begin with it is best you should gain all the configuration knowledge and clear ADM201 later you can start working on Developer track once you are done with the Admin Stuff.

To prepare for the certification I would recommend you to watch this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_xOXdvuf5c

it explains how to crack the certification exams using trailhead.
Also there is a beautiful post which guide you how to clear all salesforce certification

http://www.sfdc99.com/2014/10/02/guide-to-passing-all-salesforce-certifications/

Best wishes for your future endeavors.